# slugs.map is not a function error when generating dynamic sitemap

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js

I'd like to generate a dynamic sitemap depend of my slugs paths. I use `next-sitemap` library: https://github.com/iamvishnusankar/next-sitemap.

When I want to enter `http://localhost:3000/server-sitemap.xml` there is an error
`slugs.map is not a function` in `../pages/server-site.xml/index.js`.

`next-sitemap.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  siteUrl: "https://mywebsite.vercel.app/",
  changefreq: "daily",
  priority: 0.7,
  //   sitemapSize: 5000,
  generateRobotsTxt: true,
  exclude: ["/server-sitemap.xml"],

  robotsTxtOptions: {
    policies: [
      {
        userAgent: "*",
        allow: "/",
      },
    ],
    additionalSitemaps: [
      "https://mywebsite.vercel.app/server-sitemap.xml",
    ],
  },
};
```

`../pages/server-site.xml/index.js`

```js
import { getServerSideSitemap } from "next-sitemap";
import { getPortfolioSlugs } from "../../lib/data";

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Method to source urls from cms
  const slugs = await getPortfolioSlugs();

  const fields = slugs.map((slug) => ({
    loc: `https://mywebsite.vercel.app/portfolio/${slug.slug}`,
    lastmod: new Date().toISOString(),
  }));

  return getServerSideSitemap(ctx, fields);
};

export default function Sitemap() {}
```

The GraphQL request:

```js
import { GraphQLClient, gql } from "graphql-request";
const endpoint = process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPHCMS_API;

export const getPortfolioSlugs = async () => {
  const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(endpoint);

  const query = gql`
    {
      portfolios {
        slug
      }
    }
  `;
  return await graphQLClient.request(query);
};
```

GraphCMS API playground `getPortfolioSlugs()` query returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "portfolios": [
      {
        "slug": "kostka-brukowa-test"
      },
      {
        "slug": "kostka-cypryjska"
      },
      {
        "slug": "granito"
      },
      {
        "slug": "carmino"
      },
      {
        "slug": "test-xxx"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

In `PortfolioList`, I `console.log(slugs)` from this props.

```js
// (...)
export const getServerSideProps = async () => { 
  const slugs = await getPortfolioSlugs(); 
  return { props: { slugs: slugs.portfolios, }, }; 
}; 

const PortfolioList = ({slugs }) => {
  console.log(slugs);
return (
//(...)
)}
// (...)
```

[image]

Comment: The error indicates that `slugs` is not an array (doesn't have the `map` method). If you log `slugs` to the terminal, what does it output?

Comment: I can't `console.log(slugs)` beacuase there are bunch of errors with getServerSideProps, but  in my API Playground shows the getPortfolioSlugs query. I updated the question you can check what it returns.

Comment: I just did console.log of `getPortfolioSlugs()` in other of my Page and it retruns what the API Playground did - an array of objects

Comment: The data returned by the GraphQL query is an object, though. What exactly are you logging to the console in that last image?

Comment: ``` export const getServerSideProps = async () => { const slugs = await getPortfolioSlugs();  return {
    props: {
      slugs: slugs.portfolios,
    },
  };
}; ``` I'm loging `slugs` from this props.

Comment: Yeah, so that's not the same as `slugs` from the `getServerSideProps` code you showed in `server-site.xml/index.js`. You need to map through `slugs.portfolios` instead inside `getServerSideProps`, i.e. `const fields = slugs.portfolios.map(...);`

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll try right now. I clarified the edit 2-3 what it looks like the console.log in the question.

Comment: It works!!!! Thank you, I've learnt sth new.I'm kinda a noob with graphql and backend stuff etc. You can answer my question with that :) Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data returned by the GraphQL query is an object, hence the error about `.map` not being a function when you try to call it on `slugs`.

The array you want to map should be accessible under `slugs.portfolios`.

```js
// /pages/server-site.xml/index.js
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
    const slugs = await getPortfolioSlugs();
    // Change following line
    const fields = slugs.portfolios.map((slug) => ({
        loc: `https://mywebsite.vercel.app/portfolio/${slug.slug}`,
        lastmod: new Date().toISOString(),
    }));

    return getServerSideSitemap(ctx, fields);
};
```